# SQL query from multiple tables with complicated condition

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have THE Following TABLES:

```
1- EMP_INFO_STATUS (main table)
2- NEW_EMP_PERSONAL
3- NEW_EMP_NOTE
4- NEW_EMP_CRS
5- NEW_EMP_CER
6- EMPLOYEES
```

I want sql statement that

returns all the records in table EMP_INFO_STATUS if:

- STATUS calum in EMP_INFO_STATUS table = 2
  ==AND==
- employee has records in table NEW_EMP_CRS
  OR
- employee has records in table NEW_EMP_CER
  OR
- employee has records in table NEW_EMP_NOTE
  OR
- employee has records in table NEW_EMP_PERSONAL (AND) a clomn called SECONDMENT_IMAGE is not Null

and this sql doesn't work

```
SELECT A.EMP_NO,A.STATUS, 
        B.EMPLOYEE_NO,B.EMP_1ST_NAME,B.EMP_2ND_NAME,
        B.EMP_3RD_NAME,B.EMP_4TH_NAME
FROM p9.EMP_INFO_STATUS A, 
     p9.EMPLOYEES B, 
     p9.NEW_EMP_PERSONAL C, 
     p9.NEW_EMP_NOTE D, 
     p9.NEW_EMP_CRS E, 
     p9.NEW_EMP_CER F
WHERE
        A.EMP_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO
    AND A.EMP_NO = C.EMP_NO(+)
    AND A.EMP_NO = C.EMP_NO(+)
    AND A.EMP_NO = E.EMP_NO(+)
    AND A.EMP_NO = F.EMP_NO(+)
    AND A.STATUS = 2 
    AND (
                C.SECONDMENT_IMAGE is not NULL 
            OR  C.NOTES is not NULL 
            OR  D.NOTE is not NULL 
            OR  E.EMP_NO IS NOT NULL 
            OR  F.EMP_NO IS NOT NULL
        )
    GROUP BY A.EMP_NO, A.STATUS, B.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
             B.EMP_1ST_NAME,B.EMP_2ND_NAME,
             B.EMP_3RD_NAME,B.EMP_4TH_NAME
```

Comment: There is no need to shout

Comment: ___Does not work??___ Not a very helpful description. In what way does it not work.

Comment: it returns an employee who has data in table C but the secondment_image column and notes column were null

Comment: You might like to look at using the JOIN syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this untested select statement:

```
SELECT InnerQuery.EMP_NO
     , InnerQuery.STATUS
     , Employees.EMPLOYEE_NO
     , Employees.EMP_1ST_NAME
     , Employees.EMP_2ND_NAME
     , Employees.EMP_3RD_NAME
     , Employees.EMP_4TH_NAME
FROM 
(
    SELECT A.EMP_NO
         , A.STATUS
         , B.EMPLOYEE_NO
         , COUNT(B.EMPLOYEE_NO) +
           COUNT(C.EMPLOYEE_NO) +
           COUNT(D.EMPLOYEE_NO) +
           COUNT(E.EMPLOYEE_NO) +
           COUNT(F.EMPLOYEE_NO) as subrecords
    FROM p9.EMP_INFO_STATUS A
    LEFT JOIN p9.EMPLOYEES B
        ON B.EMPLOYEE_NO = A.EMP_NO 
        AND B.SECONDMENT_IMAGE IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN p9.NEW_EMP_PERSONAL C
        ON C.EMP_NO = A.EMP_NO
    LEFT JOIN p9.NEW_EMP_NOTE D
        ON D.EMP_NO = A.EMP_NO
    LEFT JOIN p9.NEW_EMP_CRS E
        ON E.EMP_NO = A.EMP_NO
    LEFT JOIN p9.NEW_EMP_CER F
        ON F.EMP_NO = A.EMP_NO
    WHERE A.STATUS = 2
    GROUP BY A.EMP_NO
    HAVING subrecords > 0
    -- this may need to be: HAVING COUNT(B.EMPLOYEE_NO) + COUNT(C.EMPLOYEE_NO) + COUNT(D.EMPLOYEE_NO) + COUNT(E.EMPLOYEE_NO) + COUNT(F.EMPLOYEE_NO) > 0
)
LEFT JOIN p9.EMPLOYEES Employees
    ON Employees.EMPLOYEE_NO = InnerQuery.EMP_NO;
```

Comment: I removed the table alias and added a having clause instead